# How do I return a single Model when working with nested relationships?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a Laravel Project (v6.5.1) with a MySQL DB (v5.7) which is primarily for organising football matches. I'm a bit stuck on querying all of my models as it is getting a bit complicated now. Let me explain further so it makes a bit more sense:

The structure is as follows:

Each club is independant.

Club table (id, name, etc).

Each club has many seasons, lets start with season 1 for now.
**Seasons** Table (id, season number, club_id)
hasMany relationship to Match table

Each season will consist of many matches. 
**Match** Table (id, season id, some other columns)
hasMany relationship with Team

Each Match will have a bunch of players who sign up to play.
**Team** Table (id, match_id, user_id, some other columns)

First thing I need to do is, return the current season that the Club is on. I do this with the following eloquent query:

I go to the Club Table, query it using the $url (which is passed from the uri), return the first club that matches, use the hasMany relationship between Club and Season and return the newest season (as that will always be the current)

```
Club::where('url_extension', $url)->first()->seasons->sortByDesc('season')->first();
```

Now that I have the current Season model, I use the hasMany Matches relationship to the Season to return all of the Matches that are upcoming:

```
$season->matches->where('match_date_time','>=', date('Y-m-d hh:ii:ss'));
```

Now I have a collection of Matches.

When i do a foreach on my Matches collection, I can access each Match Model and then use the hasMany Team relationship (Team is usually a group of players who have signed up to play that match) which returns all of the players who opted in for playing that game.

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
           $players = $match->players;
        }
```

Essentially, from the $players collection above (which consists of all players opted in to play a match), All I want to know for each Match is, if the logged in user (e.g user_id = 3) exists in that Team for that Match or not. This will allow me to sort out my front-end to let players choose whether to "opt in" or "opt out" of the game. It will also allow me to prevent a user from opting in for a game they're already signed up for.

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you.

**Edit** (Credit to Gage LaFleur):
So I've refactored my code to the following..

```
@if($match->players->contains('user_id', auth()->id()))
<td>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('match.cancel-availability' , $club->url_extension) }}">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $match->id }}" name="match_id">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Cancel Availability</button>
</form>
</td>
@else
<td>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('match.submit-availability' , $club->url_extension) }}">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $match->id }}" name="match_id">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit Availability</button>
</form>
</td>
@endif
```

Is this "acceptable" in a blade? I'm open to better approaches, thanks all for your help so far.

Also, I've just noticed that i actually need to access the Model of the Team table (essentially that player) as it contains values such as the team theyre on, if they've paid, goals they've scored etc..

Comment: Careful when editing your question; if you keep asking new questions, they essentially invalidate the provided answers. If you need to ask a new question, then ask a new question. You can reference this one if required, but questions should be limited to a single, specific issue.

Comment: Sorry, haven't posted much on Stack Overflow. Will start this as a new post.
Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `contains()` on the players collection:

`if ($players->contains('id', Auth::id())){  }`

Comment: This works! But...Is it "acceptable" to use something like this in my blade?

```
@if($match->players->contains('user_id', auth()->id()))
opt-out button
@else
opt-in button
@endif
```

Comment: As long as you're not performing queries in your view, this is acceptable. `$match->players` _might_ execute a query, but only if `$match` is generated from a query that doesn't use eager loading (`Match::with('players') ...`). Otherwise, you're good.

Comment: Is it possible to return a single Team Model from a similar query as this:
$match->players->contains('user_id', auth()->id())

There are values i'd need to use from the Team table e.g if a player is paid

Answer (score 0):

If i've undestand correctly, the answer is pretty easy using hasManyThrough relationship. It allow you, if you have 3 tables A B C, and A has many B and B has many C, to get the C elements connected to A, and than of those records, you can select only the id and than check if the id exist in that collection

Comment: `HasManyThrow`? That's not a thing... It's `hasManyThrough()`. Also, provide some code; this currently doesn't quite answer the question (even if the approach is correct, it doesn't help if you can't provide an example)

Comment: i was referring to the return type of that relation: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough.html . Also, no database structure or Model script are posted, so i can't figure out the right code

Comment: Yes, I know what you were referring to, but it's `HasManyThrough`, not `HasManyThrow` (`Throw` is not `Through`, you spelt it wrong). And models are posted, `Club`, `Season`, `Match`, `Team`, `Player`, etc. You can provide what you think the relationships look like between them, etc. etc. Regardless, if there isn't enough information to provide an answer, don't provide an answer. You should be able to leave a comment suggesting an approach, but currently, this doesn't quite hit the mark.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't think this would work for my use case, but thanks for taking the time to try and help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the user is in the current match with an `in_array()` check in your foreach?

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $players = $match->players;
    if(in_array($players->pluck('user_id', $currentUser)->toArray())){
        //User is in this match
    }else{
        //User is not in this match
    }
}
```

There are other, probably cleaner ways to go about this, but the above is probably the easiest to drop in. If you're interested, I would suggest going about this the other way. Looping instead over the players deep relationship to the club.

Since I'm not 100% sure what data you are trying to retrieve, I'm going to assume its something like this:

CLUB -> Season (possibly variable):

1. Match

   1. Player
   2. Player
   3. etc.
2. Match

   1. Player
   2. Player
   3. etc.
3. Match
4. Etc.

and you have an authenticated user who is able to be matched with one of those `Player` models in that tree. This comes with the constraint that the user should be able to see matches they are involved in, the ability to sign up for new matches, and the ability to un-sign up for matches they've already signed up for.

Comment: Yeah this would work but ideally would like a cleaner approach if possible - maybe using Eloquent? Thanks for your time in helping. I'll keep digging about for better ways to do this :)

Comment: @MoustafaMneimneih check my edit, is that similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey @N Mahurin, see edit in main post. There is a cleaner approach which was suggested :)