# Access Team Model from a collection using logged in user_id

Tags: php, laravel

Posted the below not long ago and received some really good answers however whilst developing, my requirements became clearer. Instead of continually editing my previous post, thought I'd make a new one.

[How do I return a single Model when working with nested relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861975/how-do-i-return-a-single-model-when-working-with-nested-relationships?noredirect=1#comment103997140_58861975)

Assuming you've read my post above, I need to access the Team Model (not collection) for that particular Match for the logged in user. 
FYI, I've named the Model "Team" and then referenced the hasMany function as "players" to the Match Model.

The Team model contains a few columns such as 'match_id', 'user_id', 'team', 'team_alias', 'goals',  'assists', 'paid'. I need to be able to access these.

Something like this in mind (I want to use this in my blade):

```
@foreach($matches as $match) {
    @if($match->player->paid)
        some html showing a payment complete 
    @else
        some html showing payment required
    @endif
}
@endforeach
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

**Edit**: Adding more details for clarity

My Match Model looks like this:

```
Match {#645 ▼
  #original: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "season_id" => 1
    "venue_name" => "Wembley Stadium"
    "venue_address" => "Wembley, Something Lane, London, Postcode"
    "home_score" => null
    "away_score" => null
    "motm" => null
    "match_date_time" => "2019-11-21 10:00:00"
    "created_at" => "2019-11-13 23:14:44"
    "updated_at" => "2019-11-13 23:14:44"
  ]
}
```

I use the venue_name, venue_address and match_date_time to display a table of all matches available for a user. A few more options I need to display on this table are whether a person has paid or not. This information is stored in the Team table (once a person submits their availability).

The Team model looks like this:

```
Team {#667 ▼
  #original: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 37
    "match_id" => 5
    "user_id" => 2
    "paid" => 0
    "team" => null
    "team_alias" => null
    "goals" => null
    "assists" => null
    "created_at" => "2019-11-14 20:48:02"
    "updated_at" => "2019-11-14 20:48:02"
  ]
}
```

The Match Model is linked via id to the Team model which contains match_id.

How can I easily access the Team Model for the logged in user from this particular Match model?

Comment: can you explain better what you mean with " I need to access the Team Model (not collection) for that particular Match for the logged in user" ? you have a current logged user, which i think it's associate with a Team, but than i've understand nothing about what you want to do (i've already read your old post)

Comment: Updated question with more information. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: so you have a Match, and you what to get the Team associated with that Match and the logged user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what i've understand, you already have a Match, and a logged user, and you want to find the Team where the logged user play and the Match given right?

```php
Team::where([['user_id', auth()->user()->user_id /*or the User table primary key*/], ['match_id', $match->match_id /*or the Match table primary key*/]])
```

or, if you have already implement the realtionship from Match and Team inside the Model, you can do something like

```php
$match->teams()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->user_id /*or the User table primary key*/)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need to do this bit of functionality in my blade. Any objections to doing an eloquent where query in my blade?

Comment: Well, you che use \@php \@endphp and write inside some codes, but it’s not that great, but if you have to put this code inside a if statement, can’t see the problem... just consider to prefetch the teams with “-> with(‘teams’)” function on your controller, in order to avoid running a query every iteration of you foreach loop